# Recursion in Python

Tags: python, recursion

The problem is about writing a recursive function, "def EhMensuravel (target, weight)"
that determines whether it is possible to measure the value desired target with a given set of weights on a twin-pan balance. The weights available are stored in the list "weights". 
Remebering that the weights can be placed on the plate opposite that is occupied by the target weight, on the same plate of the target weight or be not used.

The code I made is that, but something is wrong.

```
weights = [1, 2, 3]
matrix = []

def createaMatrix():
    for i in range(len(weights)):
        matrix.append([])
    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(len(weights)):
            if j==0:
                matrix[j].append(weights[i])
            if j==1:
                matrix[j].append(-weights[i])
            if j==2:
                matrix[j].append(0)

createMatrix()


def EhMensuravel(entry, weights, final_weight=0):
    if final_weight == entry:
        return True
    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(len(weight)):
            final_weight += matrix[i][j]
            return EhMensuravel(entry, weight[1:], final_weight)
```

EDIT: For example, When I try `print EhMensuravel(4, weights)`, the output is:

```
>>> 
1
2
3
None
>>>
```

Comment: "Something is wrong." Please edit your question to say *what* is wrong.

Comment: Please share the output of your program, and also how you are running it.

Comment: You are returning from the `for` loops in your `EhMensuravel` functions. This means it will only ever use `j = 0` and `i = 0` (unless `len(weights)` is 0, in which case the function will return `None` as the inner loop will not run).

Comment: But how I can fix it? I think when I do 
     return EhMensuravel(entry, weights[1:], final_weight)     
"weights[1:]" is also wrong, but I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the recursion very simple even without the global matrix like this

```
weights = [1, 2, 3]

def EhMensuravel(entry, weights, weight_idx = 0):
    if entry == 0:
        return True

    if weight_idx == len(weights):
        return False

    if EhMensuravel(entry + weights[weight_idx], weights, weight_idx+1):
        return True

    if EhMensuravel(entry - weights[weight_idx], weights, weight_idx+1):
        return True

    if EhMensuravel(entry, weights, weight_idx+1):
        return True

    return False

print EhMensuravel(4, weights)
```

The first if statement just says that 0 is measurable. The second if just assures that there are still weights left. The next 3 recursive calls just update the current weight `entry` by adding, subtracting or ignoring the current weight and restart the search from the next weight. If no solution was found, then False is returned.

Comment: note that wasserfeder did not implement an iteration when recursion was desired, and i don't think you can implement a recursion during an iteration, since the iteration is itself recursive